# Set cURL address via POST variable

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I have been trying to use cURL in PHP with a dynamic address (i.e. set via a POST variable) but it isn't working!

```
<?php
$address = $_POST['address'];

//echo $address;
//$address = "http://twitter.com";

$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL, $address);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

if (empty($buffer)) {
    echo "Sorry, ".$address." are a bunch of poopy-heads.<p>";
}
else {
    echo $buffer;
}
?>
```

I know the POST is working, because I can echo the $address variable and see the contents of $address that I sent.

Comment: So what errors or problem do you have? Not working is not good enough

Comment: check your `$_POST['address']`

Comment: the $_POST['address'] works fine, see the bottom line of my question.

Comment: There are no errors, it just doesn't return any contents of any address I specify via POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an input sanitation issue, in which there was a space in the $address variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now since you know `$_POST` is working, let's look at your cURL.

This is the function I'm usually using. Maybe you can give it a try?

**Code :**

```
function getCurl(
                $url,
                $returntransfer=1, $httpproxytunnel=1, $referer=null,
                $useragent=null, $header=null, $httpheader=null,
                $proxy=null, $port=null
                )
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $returntransfer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, $httpproxytunnel);

    if ($referer!=null)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    if ($useragent!=null)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
    if ($header!=null)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    if ($httpheader!=null)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpheader);
    if ($proxy!=null)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    if ($port!=null)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);

    $result['DATA'] = curl_exec($ch);
    $result['INFO'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $result['ERROR'] = curl_error($ch); 

    return $result;
}

function getFile($url)
{
    $data = getCurl($url);

    return $data['DATA'];
}
```

**And use it like this :**

```
<?php
     $fileContents = getFile("http://www.somedomain.com/a-path-to-your-file.html");
     echo $fileContents;
?>
```

Comment: so why add all the extra options if your not going to use em?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Because I sometimes may need to... ;-)

Comment: Hmm... I tried

    $fileContents = getFile($address);
    echo $fileContents;

and it still doesn't work.

Comment: then in that case you should use `return $data;` so you have access to the errors & info array ;p

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Since you say that you CAN get `$_POST['address']`, why not just try it the easiest way : what does `echo file_get_contents($address)` return?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Yep Charles, that's exactly what I was about to say. Of course, you may add an `echo $data['ERROR']` in `getFile`... if you wish, that is... :-)

Comment: `Warning: file_get_contents( http://twitter.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cjt3007/public_html/console/getDATA.php on line 65`

Comment: Hmm... with the `$data['ERROR'];` added, I get this error: `Protocol http not supported or disabled in libcurl`

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII What if you try `echo file_get_contents($address,false);`? - let's make sure it's NOT looking for the url in the parent folder...

Comment: A hah!, I think I figured it out. For some reason a space is being added to the beginning of the `$address` prior to being sent to this page via POST. SMH

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Damn! The thing is that `( http://twitter.com)` (with the gap at the beginning) struck me as a bit weird... though I imagined it was some sort of copy-pasting mistake...

Comment: All is working fine now, I just didn't do a `replace(' ','');` on the input. *facepalm*